# Spring WebFlux: Unit Testing subscribe function of Mono

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito, reactor

I have the following classes/interfaces:

```java
public interface Api {
    Mono<Object> update();
}
```

```java
@Service
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    private Api api;
    private List<Object> list;

    public void update() {
        api.update().subscribe(result -> list.add(result), Throwable::printStackTrace);    
    }
}
```

I'm trying to perform a unit test using Mockito of the consumer function when I subscribe to the Mono that is being returned by my Api. So far, my test class looks as follows

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private Mono<Object> mono;
    @MockBean
    private Api api;
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        when(api.update()).thenReturn(mono);
        doAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> {
            System.out.println("FOO");
            Consumer<Object> consumer = invocation.getArgument(0);
            consumer.accept(testObject)
            return null;
        }).when(mono).subscribe(any(Consumer.class), any(Consumer.class));

       service.update();
    }
}
```

First, I am seeing that the code inside doAnswer() never gets invoked. Secondly, since Mockito's any() returns null and the error consumer of subscribe function expects non-null I'm running into NullPointerException when I run my test.

What would be the best approach of going about unit testing my subscribe's consumer function?

Comment: What version of `reactor` are you using? The only [subscribe method](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-java.util.function.Consumer-) I find returns a `Disposable`. Note that the method is `final` so mockito won't be able to handle it by default. You will need to configure it properly, check [here](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39).

Comment: The more important question would be what are you trying to test here? Shouldn't it be that the `testObject` (whatever that is) is added into the `list` within `Service`. However you don't have a method to access the content of that list so you might want to use reflections here.